# Best practice of handling empty (zero) month or day in MySQL via Spring Boot JPA

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, datetime

I am currently working on parsing huge xml dump to put into mysql.
By getting some head sample data, I realized there are empty day or month for each entity, but occasionally. i.e. "1994-00-00" or "1994-06-00", or hopefully "1994-06-03".

I know MySQL supports empty date after ver 5 with some configuration, but then a friend of mine who is currently working as a DBA told me about the sys date (new for me. I am not a DBA but eager to learn about!)

Now, with all due respect, I would like to ask you all. What would be the best practice to deal with this kind of situation? Should I simply put some dummy date? or should I touch sys date that my friend told me about? or is there any other solutions for me to deal with this?

I am currently connecting to MySQL via Spring Boot JPA with the driver, but I am eager to explore best fitted solution.

p.s.The whole project is solely for xml parsing and put them to MySQL. If no good solution is presented, I may look into mongoDB...... : /

Comment: First of all, `1994-00-00` is not an _empty_ date, it is just a bogus date, which can't even actually exist in a proper MySQL date column.  Regarding date columns, are you storing your dates as text, or in date columns?

Comment: Thank you for the early comment. Yes, that is exactly my concern, as of 00 value is not a valid value for date column. I even considered to store the date in text, however, was simply feel horrible to think of how I could deal later on with that. Still not sure which way to go... :(

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . MySQL supports "relaxed" date formats which do allow 0s for months and dates (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6c9fdfb8b7db7e870c050464d4656942).

Comment: What exactly does 1994-00-00 mean or represent? E.g. someone's birth year when full birthday is unknown?

Comment: It is for record (music) release date. Yes, I could say, a birthday example is also suitable in this case: unknown month and day but the year is consistent.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Oh, the horror...the horror.

Comment: Decided to avoid exploiting 00 values for now! Thank you all for enlightenments... :)

Comment: Curiously `1994-06-00` isn’t a valid date i XML. Only valid dates are (dates that exist in real human beings’ calendars).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the meaning of `2020-00-00` or `2021-03-00` in your application?

Do they refer to the first day of the year or month mentioned? In that case you should get your Java code to turn them into `2020-01-01` and `2021-03-01` respectively, so the values refer to actual calendar days.

Do they refer to the entire year or month? In that case you will need to dream up a way of representing an interval of time in your table. Maybe you could add a second date column called `end_date` filled in like this

```
value from xml     date        end_date
2020-04-07       2020-04-07   2020-04-07  a day
2020-00-00       2020-01-01   2020-12-31  a year
2020-03-00       2020-03-01   2020-03-31  a month
```

Only you, or the person who made the xml, can know what those incomplete dates actually mean.

If I were you I would only insert valid date values into the table, and avoid exploiting MySql's dummy-date feature. If I used MongoDB I would do the same.

Comment: I think the authors didn't know where to find the original release dates, hence simply leaving blank for month and day field other than year. I think I need more time to consider which approach to take but for now, I will try your solution. Thanks!

Comment: I saw your comment about record release dates after I wrote my answer.  In your case, I would use both a DATE column and a VARCHAR column for the release date. Your DATE will be used for searching `WHERE date BETWEEN '1973-01-01' AND '1974-12-31'`, and your VARCHAR for display. The VARCHAR contains what you actually know about the date. `1973`, `April 1973`, or `15 April 1973` (formatted appropriately for your needs of course). This follows the way libraries keep their catalogs.

Comment: Thank you! It seems logical to be kept that way. I will post the result and throughputs after implementation. Thank you so much :D

Comment: Good Answer. But I would suggest the consistent use of the Half-Open approach to defining a span of time. In Half-Open, the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. So the year of 2020 begins with 2020-01-01 and runs up to, but does not include, 2021-01-01. The month of 2020-03 begins with 2020-03-01 and runs up to, but does not include, 2020-04-01. The *java.time* classes uses Half-Open by default for good reason.

Comment: Tip: The *ThreeTen-Extra* library provides the `LocalDateRange` class to represent the spans of time discussed here. Pass a pair of `LocalDate` objects. Then use convenient comparison methods such as contains, abuts, overlaps, and so on.